# Page numbering wrong - LaTeX not incrementing

Tags: page-numbering

I'm writing this questions since I couldn't find any solution here or elswhere on the internet. There are lots of questions, referring to wrong page numbers in the ToC but appearently none with my issue.

I got some strange behaviour, where LaTeX will seemingly randomly not increment a page number (After page 50 follows page 50). The references in ToC are all correct.
I have no idea, where this behaviour comes from. First i thought it would be related to referencing a table on a previous page, although it is just appearing on the next page. Moving the text with the reference to the same page didn't make any difference. Compiling with pdfLaTeX multiple times didn't fix it either.

Does anybody know where this behaviour can come from ? It seems to be related to tabularx environments and the ltablex package I'm using. (It wraps every tabularx in a longtable)

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside,parskip=half,headings=normal]{scrreprt} 

%%% Präambel %%%
% hier sollten keine Änderungen erforderlich sein
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % Zeichencodierung UTF-8 für Eingabe-Dateien
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % Darstellung von Umlauten im PDF

\usepackage{listings}         % für Einbindung von Code-Listings
\lstset{numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=5pt,texcl=true}
\lstset{literate=             % erlaubt Sonderzeichen in Code-Listings 
{Ö}{{\"O}}1
{Ä}{{\"A}}1
{Ü}{{\"U}}1
{ß}{{\ss}}2
{ü}{{\"u}}1
{ä}{{\"a}}1
{ö}{{\"o}}1
{€}{{\euro}}1
}

\usepackage[
  inner=35mm,outer=15mm,top=25mm,
  bottom=20mm,foot=12mm,includefoot
]{geometry}                 % Einstellungen für Ränder

% \usepackage{morefloats} % More floats

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Spracheinstellungen Deutsch
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anf.zeichen
\usepackage{enumerate}      % anpassbare Nummerier./Aufz.
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Einbinden von Grafiken
\usepackage{svg}        %SVG Grafiken
\usepackage{ltablex}    % Tables over multiple rows
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % Figures next to text
\usepackage{booktabs}   % Rules for more pretty tables
\usepackage{tikz}       
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}    % Ckeckmark
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % anderthalbzeilig

\usepackage{blindtext}      % Textgenerierung für Testzwecke
\usepackage{color}          % Verwendung von Farbe 

\usepackage{acronym}        % für ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis


\usepackage{hyperref}       % URL-Formatierung, klickbare Verweise

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}        % für Verzeichnis der Anhänge

\newcounter{anhcnt}
\setcounter{anhcnt}{0}
\newlistof{anhang}{app}{}

\newcommand{\anhang}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{anhcnt}
  \setcounter{anhteilcnt}{0}
  \section*{Anhang \theanhcnt: #1}
  \addcontentsline{app}{section}{\protect\numberline{A.\theanhcnt}#1}\par
}

\newcounter{anhteilcnt}
\setcounter{anhteilcnt}{0}

\newcommand{\anhangteil}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{anhteilcnt}
    \subsection*{Teil~\arabic{anhteilcnt}: #1}
    \addcontentsline{app}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{Teil~\arabic{anhteilcnt}}#1}\par  
}

\renewcommand{\theanhteilcnt}{Anhang \theanhcnt~-- Teil~\arabic{anhteilcnt}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}                % fortlaufende Zähler für Fußnoten, Abbildungen und Tabellen
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 


\usepackage{textcomp}            % erlaubt EUR-Zeichen in Eingabedatei
\usepackage{eurosym}             % offizielles EUR-Symbol in Ausgabe
\renewcommand{\texteuro}{\euro}  % ACHTUNG: nach hyperref aufrufen!

\usepackage{scrhack}             % stellt Kompatibilität zw. KOMA-Script
                                 % (scrreprt) und anderen Paketen her

% Anpassung der Abstände bei Kapitelüberschriften
% (betrifft auch Inhalts-, Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichnis)
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-\topskip}}
\newcommand{\myBeforeTitleSkip}{1mm}
\newcommand{\myAfterTitleSkip}{10mm}
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{\myBeforeTitleSkip}
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{\myBeforeTitleSkip}
\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{\myBeforeTitleSkip}

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{\myAfterTitleSkip}
\setlength\cftafterloftitleskip{\myAfterTitleSkip}
\setlength\cftafterlottitleskip{\myAfterTitleSkip}                                                            
%%% Ende der Präambel %%%

\begin{document}

%%% Umstellung der Seiten-Nummerierung auf i, ii, iii ... %%%
\pagenumbering{Roman} 

%%% Inhalts-, Abbildungs-, Tabellenverzeichnisse %%%
% sollen einzeilig gesetzt werden, um Platz zu sparen 
\begin{spacing}{1}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis} % Abb.verz. ins Inh.verz. aufnehmen
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}   % Tab.verz. ins Inh.verz. aufnehmen
\listoftables
\end{spacing}

%%% Umstellung der Seiten-Nummerierung auf 1, 2, 3 ... %%%
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Lorem}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor}


\subsection{Lorem ipsum}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{  >{\hsize=.45\hsize}X | >{\hsize=.275\hsize} X | >{\hsize=.075\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X | >{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}
    \toprule
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit a     &Lorem ipsum dolor sit ae & Lorem & Lorem ipsum dolor sit \\
    \midrule
    ALorem ipsum dolor sit a  & Lorem ipsum & \checkmark & Lorem ipsum dolor sit a  \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit am ipsum dolor sit a  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit a   & \checkmark & Lorem ipsum dolor sit a  \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum   & \checkmark &Lorem ipsum   \\
    \midrule
Lorem ipsum & Lorem & \checkmark & Lorem ipsum\\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum     & Lorem  & \checkmark & Lorem ipsum \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & O & Lorem ipsum \\  \midrule
    Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & \checkmark & Lorem ipsum    \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum & \checkmark & Lorem ipsum    \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum     & Lorem ipsum &\checkmark & Lorem ipsum \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum &Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsum &Lorem ipsum \\
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Lorem ipsum} \label{tab:tab1} \\

\end{tabularx}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r \\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{  X | X}
    \toprule    
    Lorem ipsum & Lorem ipsuml  \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum &Lorem ipsum    \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsuml        & Lorem ipsum   \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum &  Lorem ipsum  \\
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Lorem ipsum} \label{tab:lorem} \\
\end{tabularx}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.t, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X| X}
     \toprule
    Lorem & Lorem \\
    \midrule
    Lorem ipsum         & Lorem ipsum \\
    Lorem ipsum             & Lorem ipsum \\
    Lorem ipsum         & Lorem ipsum \\
    Lorem ipsum             & Lorem ipsum\\
    Lorem ipsum         &Lorem ipsum \\
    Lorem ipsum             & Lorem ipsum \\
    Lorem ipsum         & Lorem ipsum \\
    Lorem ipsum             & Lorem ipsum\\
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}\label{tab:tab_lorem} \\
\end{tabularx}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.t, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, seLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.t, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, se

\end{document}
```

Comment: it isn't really possible to debug code that we can not run. Please fix your posted code so that it can be run and demonstrates the problem. As it is the problem might be in the class file that you have not stated (best to use article class in the example if the problem occurs with that)

Comment: Well if the behaviour starts on page 50 it is improbable that something in the preamble is triggering it. You will have to make a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: And of course; Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I added at least my documentclass. I know that it is likely, that the problem occurs in the code of the pages, where i suddenly get two pages not incrementing. I included the preamble, because i thought it might have been caused by incompatibilities of the packages I'm using. I already looked for similarities, that might cause them, but I could'nt find them. I'll further slice and dice my code trying to get a MWE.

Comment: Finally i was able to create a MWE. Kindly have a look at my edit. I guess the problem is related to tabularx and ltablex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ltablex` has a few "issues" but anyway this looks suspicious

```
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X| X}
     \toprule
```

starting a full width table mid paragraph, if I change it to

```
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r 

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X| X}
     \toprule
```

Then I get page numbers 1,2,3,4 not 1,2,3,3

Comment: Awesome, this really was the reason. I would've never figured out. Thanks a lot.